# Javascript ternary operator and assignment

Tags: javascript, variable-assignment, ternary

I get unexpected result for this simple JavaScript assignment statement:

```
var t = 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0;
undefined
```

I would have expected to get 1 assigned to t instead. Same result if you do

```
var t = (1 == 1 ? 1 : 0);
undefined
```

Can somebody explain why this does not work as expected?

Comment: Are you doing this in a console? If so, just type `t` after your assignment code to see the actual value that `t` has. I know that WebKit consoles behave like this.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the operator, it has to deal with not understanding how the debugger works.

Answer (score 31):

The result of evaluating `var t = 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0;` in, say, the Firebug console will be `undefined`. However, the value of `t` will be `1` as expected. Try outputting `t` after the assignment.

Firebug *will* print the result when the variable declaration is on a separate line:

```
var t;
t = 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0;
```

This is because the return value of an assignment operation is the value being assigned. However, when the `var` keyword is present, what's returning is the value of the VariableStatement declaration, which behaves as follows:

> The production *VariableStatement* : **var**
>   *VariableDeclarationList*; is evaluated
>   as follows: Evaluate
>   *VariableDeclarationList*. Return
>   (normal, empty, empty).

Where `Return (normal, empty, empty).` refers to a type recognized by JavaScript internally, not something that would be printed to the console.

Further reading:

http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.2

Answer (score 17):

It works perfectly:

```
> var t = 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0;
undefined
> t
1
```

<del>You could say that the return value of the *assignment operation* is `undefined`, not the value of `t`.</del>

---

*Edit:* But actually [if I read the specification correctly](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.13.1), it seems that it should return the value of the expression.

As @T.J. Crowder mentioned, it seems the `var` is responsible for the `undefined` value. But that does not mean that you should not use `var`. The code you wrote is 100% correct.

This goes more into the inner workings of the language and I think that is not what you are interested in. Bur for more information about that, have a look at the comments.

Comment: Actually, the value of an *assignment operation* is the assigned value. The `var` keyword, however, gets in the way in consoles, apparently. (Since `var` can't appear on the right-hand side of an expression, that doesn't surprise me; seems a valid way to deal with the console aspect.)

Comment: @TJCrowder: True, seems to be the `var`. Thanks for the insight.

Comment: What happens is that the `var` statement returns a *normal completion* with no value, the *value of an assignment operation* is clearly the value of the assigned expression, e.g.: `var a; alert(a = 'foo'); alert(a);` will alert `'foo'` twice... Some time ago I was writing an article about the *completion type*, but I haven't time to finish it yet, here's an old [draft](http://j.mp/gI9IRv).

Comment: @TJCrowder, @CMS: I just had a look at [this part of the specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_12.2) and there it is written that the evaluation returns `(normal, empty, empty)` so I guess this is what you mean by "normal completion" (which I could confirm after having a look at your draft). Thank you for that!

Comment: @CMS: And once again I notice I should not talk so much about things I have no full insight ;)

Comment: @CMS: I was just reading the spec and responding with a similar answer. It was clear to me that `Return (normal, empty, empty)` was referring to some internal return type, but I wasn't familiar with the terminology. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 4):

In old javascript parsers we need to conclude the condition in parentheses:

```
var t = (1 == 1) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I've been using JavaScript in browser implementations since 1996. I've never once seen one get the order of precedence wrong. Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 1):

This code works fine:

```
var t = 1 == 1 ? 1 : 0;
alert (t);
```

Check [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gorsky/jT9hU/). It shows **1**.